# Excel Data table - preserve manual entries in one column

Tags: sql, excel, datatable

I have the following table layout in an Excel data table (fed by a SQL query):

```
Name, Birthday, Children, Check In
```

The first three columns come from a database query, the `Check In` column should be a column where I can manually enter an `x` for example.

Now, when I refresh the data table, the entries in the last column should stay in the right row. Currently, when I refresh the table the entries stay in the very same row they were entered in (e.g. if you enter an x into row 4, refresh and row 4 becomes row 5, the x stays in row 4).

Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would Excel "know" that row 4 became row 5? It is simply replacing the values in the first 3 columns with values from the database. The only way I can think of to achieve what you want would be to keep a copy of the initial data, and match it to the new data to provide the value for `Check In`.

Comment: I thought that this would be the case, I was hoping it wasnt.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have some ID that uniquely identifies each item in each row (you could use the Name column if you don't have duplicate names). Keep a copy of your old data that you have marked the "Check In" box for. Then do a basic VLOOKUP to see whether that name has check in.